# How to add footer Miscellaneous HTML in Magento 2.1?

Tags: magento-2.1

Trying to add Miscellaneous HTML in the footer section of Magento 2.1 but I cannot locate this field anymore in our Magento 2.1.0 store, see screenshot below:

[image: Magento 2.1 backend]

In Magento 2.0 the same page had many more sections: Design Theme, HTML Head, Header, Footer, Product Image Watermarks, Pagination & Emails, see screenshot below:

[image: Magento 2.0 backend]

Does anyone know if these sections have moved elsewhere in Magento 2.1? Can't seem to find these anywhere in my backend...

Any chance this could be because of the Porto theme used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to go for Admin:

Go To,

> Content -> Design -> Configuration

Now go to your current theme,

Click on current theme you have to display new page opened,
Inside This page,
You have to go for **footer section** at below of page, Inside footer you can add your `Miscellaneous HTML` section.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Rakesh's answer.

[image: The Html Location]